# What can be used to protect the under-carriage of a hot rod?

Tags: chevrolet, body, body-work, hotrod, c10

With a sand blasted cab and bed I am looking for a solution to protect the metal body of a C10 hot rod on air ride.  I have looked into possibly rhino lining the under side of the bed and cab but I wanted to know if there is another solution since I am not a paint and body expert.  I would prefer a paintable solution but since the stance is low I do not mind leaving it alone as long as it's black to match the frame.

Comment: On bare metal use self etching primer then epoxy primer, then a color coat to match the body paint if you wish, then a coat of your favorite undercoating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use epoxy primer to start. You can then spray paintable undercoat on your frame, underbody.

They come in various forms as depicted in the image below.

[image]

You may also use a rocker guard type product as shown.

To my personal taste, I would seal with epoxy primer, rubberized undercoat, and then oil undercoating to protect even further. Application is very straight forward if you are working with clean metal. If not, make sure you are not applying the products over unprepared surfaces.

[image]

Oil undercoating is the process of spraying oil on your vehicles underbelly to aid in rust prevention. Most vehicles will have plugs in their doors which can be removed so they can be blasted as well. For optimal results in climates like Canada, you can do this at least once a year.

Here are pictures of the process.

[image][image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about what an "oil undercoating" is? Applying oil on top of a rubber coating doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I updated my post. Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Oil undercoating, that sounds environmentally sound....

Comment: @Moab It's generally a plant-based oil, like Peanut-Oil.